# How to deal with my co-worker who constantly cuts in to conversation?

Tags: work-environment, workplace-rhythm

I have a co-worker who is a motor mouth and constantly cuts in to conversations she isn't involved in as soon as she walks into the room. I'm over it but want to tell her that in a nice way. How should I go about doing so?

Comment: You are trying to tell her (1) "you are over it" or (2) "she needs to stop cutting in on conversation"? Please clarify.

Comment: What's your question? What are you trying to do with "deal with?" This can mean a _lot_ of things.

Comment: Flagging your post as a duplicate. [There are many post on Workplace about this](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/search?q=is%3Aq+interrupt)

Comment: Generally if someone is in a room where a conversation is going on, that person has a right to contribute to it. If you don't want her to be a part of your conversation, go to a private location.

Comment: I am not convinced the question this is a supposed duplicate of is one. THat deals with someone trying to do non-conversational work without interruptions but not conversation interruptions which are entirely differnt and may reuire differnt handling. That said, I don't think there is adequate information to really address this. Why shouldn't she get involved in a conversation that is happening in the same room she is in? It isn't eavesdropping when you share space and she cannot help but hear.The actions might be different depending on why you do not want her in the conversation.